# httpsでアクセスしても、受信箱や実績のリンクがhttpのままになっている

Tags: バグ, 完了

普段、[**https**://ja.stackoverflow.com/](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)で参照しています。
基本的には問題ないのですが、ページ左上の「受信箱」「実績」に表示されるリンクがhttpsでなくhttpになっていて不便です。自動的に現在使用しているプロトコル（http or https）に切り替えることはできないでしょうか？
技術的にはドメイン相対URL `/～` やプロトコル相対URL `//ja.stackoverflow.com/～` を使用すれば解決すると思いますが…。

---

Normally I am using `https://ja.stackoverflow.com` (HTTPS instead of HTTP).

There usually isn't any problem, but when I look at links in the inbox or achievements they are HTTP rather than HTTPS. Is there a reason that those links can't automatically use whichever protocol you're currently using?

If the domain relative url is set to `/~` and the protocol relative url is `//ja.stackoverflow.com/~` then I think that should fix it...

Comment: 開発者と確認中です。まだSSL関連は完成していないので、時間がかかる可能性があります。フォローします。

Comment: [Network-wide HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/286934)が動き出したので再度試してみましたが、現在使用しているプロトコルに関わらず、httpsへのリダイレクトが設定されている ja.meta.so や meta.se にはhttpsで、そうでない ja.so 等にはhttpでリンクされているようですね。

Comment: いつの間にか対応されていたようなのでモデレータータグを [完了] に付け替えました。